# looking for the DiskLruCache implementation in ICS source

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-source

I am looking for the DiskLruCache implementation in ICS source (libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/DiskLruCache.java) as specified in [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) android developer guide. i tried to download entire [android source code](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html), but it taking too much time ( > 5hr still it continuing),

I also tried to use [JakeWharton's implementation of DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache), but i am not sure whether it is enough robust as implementation in ICS source.

Please suggest me an alternative download link for that. or give your own ideas..

Thanks..

Comment: Well, you can get it here: http://androidxref.com/source/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/DiskLruCache.java (though I do not know what repo this is from and therefore do not have a link in to the more-stable GitHub mirror of the AOSP). Also, AFAIK, Jake's is a pure backport.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thank you, i checked file suggested by u, and also i got it from the android source (my download is completed - 10.49gigs), both are same and depends on some of other classes in same package, but Jake Wharton's implementation of DiskLruCache avoid that dependency by implementing required functions in itself. So i think Mr.Jake Wharton s done a good job, and i am going to use that.. thanks